# Error al subir imagenes al servidor

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Espero me puedan ayudar, verán tengo lo siguiente:
Un archivo llamado **index.php** con el siguiente código:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    </head>
<body style='background-image:url(fondo/wallpaper.jpg);background-attachment:fixed;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:50% 50%;'>

    <p>
        <form action="valida_foto.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="foto" id="foto"><br>
            <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Enviar">

        </form>    

        <?php
        require_once("clase/conexion.php");
        $query = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM imagen");
        while($res = $query->fetch_assoc()){
            echo '<img src="'.$res["foto"].'" width="100" heigth="100"><br>';
        }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Y otro archivo llamado **valida_foto.php**:

```
<?php
require_once("clase/conexion.php");
if(isset($_FILES['foto'])){
    $foto=$_FILES["foto"]["name"];
    $ruta=$_FILES["foto"]["tmp_name"];
    $destino="fotos/".$foto;
    copy($ruta,$destino);
            $query = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO imagen(foto) VALUES('$destino')");

            header("Location: index.php");
            }

?>
```

Y una carpeta llamada fotos, donde se almacenaran las fotos que se suban, en este caso solo intento guardar la ruta en la base de datos, mi base se llama **fotos** y la tabla se llama **imagen** con los siguientes campos **id_imagen** y **foto**. 
El problema que a la hora que intento mostrar la foto guardada en el servidor, solo muestra lo siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Después de subir tu imagen has intentado accedes desde tu navegador a dicha imagen, es decir, suponiendo que tu index.php este sobre localhost

```
http://localhost/fotos/imagen.jpg
```

o intenta acceder a

```
http://localhost/fotos
```

y podras visualizar todos los archivos que has subido, les das click y si no visualizas los ficheros es probable que pueda ser un error de permisos el cual puedes solucionar con

```
// Lectura y escritura para el propietario, lectura para los demás
chmod("/directorio/fichero", 0644);
```

Comment: el problema es que la foto no se guarda en la carpeta "Fotos" solo se guarda la ruta en la base de datos, pero la foto no se aparece en el servidor.....

Comment: Tu código indica que la foto la esta moviendo a una carpeta fotos/nombre.jpg `copy($ruta,$destino);`, si dicha foto no aparece en tu carpeta fotos, quiere decir que no se esta copiando, quiza por que no tienes permisos sobre dicha carpeta, y solo guardas la ruta en tu base de datos, tu fichero foto debe tener permisos de escritura y lectura, puedes realizarlo con `chmod -R 666 fotos/`

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas verificar que el archivo se ha subido, considera este código para **valida_foto.php** :

```
<?php
require_once("clase/conexion.php");
if(isset($_FILES['foto'])){
  $destino="fotos/".$_FILES["foto"]["name"];
  if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['foto']['tmp_name'], $destino)){
        $query = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO imagen(foto) VALUES('$destino')");

        header("Location: index.php");

   }else{
     echo '<h1>Hay un error al subir el archivo.</h1>'
   }
} else {
  echo '<h1>No hay archivos para subir..</h1>'
}
```